# MySQL multiple-table update column assignment order

Tags: mysql, updates, multiple-tables

Reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
> right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that
> assignments are carried out in any particular order.

I can't figure out if "evaluation" is the same as "assignment"

```
set col1 = (@v := col1) + 1, col2 = @v
```

In a multiple-table update, will `col2` *always* have the original value of `col1`?

Comment: I read that documentation as a clear statement that one should not rely on the order of evaluation.